# After Filter a RecyclerView item and clicking it gives wrong item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, android-filterable

After performing filtering on Recyclerview items that are fetched through json. It's opening the wrong item when I clicked after filtering the list. Suppose A,B,C,D are in my list, and when I filter for B and click on it - it shows the wrong item (like: A,C,D) but not B. How to fix this?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class exit_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    String Show_url = "https://retrieve.php";
    public static final String EXTRA_ID = "id";
    public static final String EXTRA_V = "v";
    public static final String EXTRA_Name = "name";
    public static final String EXTRA_t = "in";
    public static final String EXTRA_o = "out";
    public static final String EXTRA_date = "date";
    public static final String EXTRA_yes = "yes";

    RecyclerView removeView;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    NetworkChangeListerner networkChangeListerner = new NetworkChangeListerner();
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ArrayList<Employee> mEmployeeList;
    private MyAdapter myadapter;
    TextInputEditText search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exit_);
        retrieveData();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ///
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refreshlayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.black, R.color.green, R.color.red);
       

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        Sprite FoldingCube = new Wave();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(FoldingCube);
      
        //
        search = findViewById(R.id.search);
        //exit
        removeView = findViewById(R.id.exit_entry);
        removeView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        removeView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mEmployeeList = new ArrayList<>();

        myadapter = new MyAdapter(exit_Activity.this, mEmployeeList);
        removeView.setAdapter(myadapter);

        //end


        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                filter(s.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Employee item : mEmployeeList) {
            if (item.getVehicle_number().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
       myadapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }


    public void retrieveData() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Show_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        mEmployeeList.clear();
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data");

                            if (sucess.equals("1")) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String vehicle_number = object.getString("number");
                                    String driver_name = object.getString("name");
                                    String entry_time = object.getString("time");
                                    String entry_date = object.getString("date");
                                    String exit_time = object.getString("ttime");
                                    String yes = object.getString("yes");
                                    mEmployeeList.add(new Employee(id, number, name, time, date, ttime, yes));
                                }
                               myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                              myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(exit_Activity.this);
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(exit_Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent ediIntent = new Intent(this, Edit_Activity.class);
        Employee clickedItem = mEmployeeList.get(position);
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, clickedItem.getId());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_V, clickedItem.getnumber());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_Name, clickedItem.getname());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_date, clickedItem.getdate());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_t, clickedItem.gettime());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_o, clickedItem.getttime());
        ediIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_yes, clickedItem.getYes());
        startActivity(ediIntent);
    }
```

**Myadapter.class:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{


    private Context mcontext;
    private ArrayList<Employee> marrayListEmployee;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Employee> arrayListEmployee) {
        mcontext = context;
        marrayListEmployee = arrayListEmployee;
    }

  /*  public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Employee> arrayListEmployee) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list_item,arrayListEmployee);

        this.context = context;
        this.arrayListEmployee = arrayListEmployee;

    }
*/
  @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View v = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
      MyViewHolder evh = new MyViewHolder(v);
      return evh;

  }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Employee currentItem = marrayListEmployee.get(position);
        String tvID = currentItem.getId();
        String tvName = currentItem.getnumber();
        holder.tvID.setText(tvID);
        holder.tvName.setText(tvName);


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return marrayListEmployee.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvID;
        public TextView tvName;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            mListener.onItemClick(position);

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
 
   public void filterList(ArrayList<Employee> filteredList) {
       marrayListEmployee = filteredList;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get element from the list that was changed after filter not the old list

```
private ArrayList<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
private void filter(String text) {
  filteredList.clear();
  for (Employee item : mEmployeeList) {
    if (item.getVehicle_number().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
      filteredList.add(item);
    }
  }
  myadapter.filterList(filteredList);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
  Intent ediIntent = new Intent(this, Edit_Activity.class);
  if(filteredList.size() > 0) {
    Employee clickedItem = filteredList.get(position);
   } else {
      Employee clickedItem = mEmployeeList.get(position);
   }
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's ArrayList<Employee> filteredList in your filter function, convert it to a field to use

Comment: 1. its duplicating items after- afterTextChanged... 2. app crashes when i select item from mEmployeeList with log: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.peeyusquad.vee.exit_Activity.onItemClick(exit_Activity.java:310)
        at com.peeyusquad.vee.MyAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:84)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7300)

Comment: duplicate problem is solved but the app crashed when I clicked on an item from a non filtered list with log: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.peeyusquad.vee.exit_Activity.onItemClick(exit_Activity.java:312)
        at com.peeyusquad.vee.MyAdapter$MyViewHolder$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:84)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7300)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7277)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:822)

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

**Sorry I didn't see the correct answer marked...**

**I will not delete, use this to improve some things**

*Don't copy/paste code because it's not tested, try to understand the changes*

In filter method you replaced marrayListEmployee with filteredList and in retrieveData method you didn set anything, just notified adapter

Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context mcontext;
    private ArrayList<Employee> marrayListEmployee;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Employee> arrayListEmployee) {
        mcontext = context;
        marrayListEmployee = arrayListEmployee;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Employee currentItem = marrayListEmployee.get(position);
        holder.tvID.setText(currentItem.getId());
        holder.tvName.setText(currentItem.getnumber());

        //TODO set setOnClickListener here instead in ViewHolder constructor
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        mListener.onItemClick(position);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return marrayListEmployee.size();
    }


    public void filterList(ArrayList<Employee> filteredList) {
        marrayListEmployee = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvID;
        public TextView tvName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity - onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         
        ......

        removeView = findViewById(R.id.exit_entry);
        removeView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        removeView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mEmployeeList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        removeView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, mEmployeeList));
        myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(this); //TODO set click listener here instead evrytime in retrieveData method
         
        .........
 
    }
```

RetrieveData data method

```
public void retrieveData() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Show_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        mEmployeeList.clear();
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("user_data");

                            if (sucess != null && sucess.equals("1")) { //check null

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String vehicle_number = object.getString("number");
                                    String driver_name = object.getString("name");
                                    String entry_time = object.getString("time");
                                    String entry_date = object.getString("date");
                                    String exit_time = object.getString("ttime");
                                    String yes = object.getString("yes");
                                    mEmployeeList.add(new Employee(id, number, name, time, date, ttime, yes));
                                }
                                //myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // remove this,
                                //myadapter.setOnItemClickListener(exit_Activity.this); remove this, set it in onCreate method
                                //TODO you have to reset mEmployeeList (below) because you changed it by filtering
                                myadapter.filterList(mEmployeeList); // change method name to swapData()
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(exit_Activity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

filter method

```
private void filter(String text) {
        if(text == null || text.isEmpty()) return;
        ArrayList<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Employee item : mEmployeeList) {
            if (item.getVehicle_number() == null) continue; // TODO check null
            if (item.getVehicle_number().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        myadapter.filterList(filteredList); // change method name to swapData()
    }
```

Comment: thanks, sir you came & answer.. but getting error at cant resolve method('int position = getAdapterPosition();')

Comment: Sorry, change this: holder.getAdapterPosition()